# Delete all files inside a folder but the last by time?

Tags: php

I have asked the same question before and I found this solution :

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/your/folder')) 
{
$files = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
{
    if (!is_dir($file))
    {
        // You'll want to check the return value here rather than just blindly adding to the array
        $files[$file] = filemtime($file);
    }
}

// Now sort by timestamp (just an integer) from oldest to newest
asort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);

// Loop over all but the 5 newest files and delete them
// Only need the array keys (filenames) since we don't care about timestamps now as the array will be in order
$files = array_keys($files);
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($files) - 5); $i++)
{
    // You'll probably want to check the return value of this too
    unlink($files[$i]);
}
}
```

And I have edited to fit my needs like this:

```
public function cleanup() {
    $files = glob("$this->location/*.sql");
    $count = count($files);
    if($count >= $this->maxbackups) {
        $timestamps = array();
        foreach( $files as $value) {
            $timestamps[$value] = filemtime($value);
        }
        asort($timestamps, SORT_NUMERIC);
        $timestamps = array_keys($timestamps);
        for ($i = 0; $i < (count($timestamps) - 1); $i++) {
            unlink($timestamps[$i]);
        }
            return $this->message->error(false,'Backups successfuly cleaned');
        } else {
            return $this->message->error(true,'Backups could not be cleaned');
        }
}
```

But the problem is that it deletes all files but the first, not the last created, why is that ?

Comment: @axiomer - Please post as an answer because this one works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `for ($i = 1; $i < (count($timestamps)); $i++)`. That could make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make it more effective and reduce complexity. (Requires only one loop, not two, neither sorting is required)

```
$files = glob("$this->location/*.sql");
if( count( $files) < 2){
  return 0; // No files deleted
}

$file = array_shift( $files);
$mTime = filemtime( $file);

foreach( $files as $currFile){
  $currTime = filemtime( $currFile);
  if( $currTime > $mTime){
    unlink( $file);
    $file = $currFile;
    $mTime = $currTime;
  } else {
    unlink( $currFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this one is good too, but I prefer my method to keep a pattern in the rest of my code. though +1 :)

Comment: @Roland yeah, I can understand that, but you're using: directory listing, loop trough files to get mtime, memory for mtime array, sort, another loop to delete files. My solution requires just one array with files (approximately  1/2 of memory your way requires), just one loop (again 1/2 of your way) and you require sorting which can get really slow... So basically you require `O(3n)`, I `O(n)`.  But you're the only one what's worth more in your situation, whether to make code effective (you require it to work for more than 50,100,1000 files every 20 seconds) or to follow paradigms.

Comment: OK, then let me try it and see what goes on, because I have some error implementation and json parsing too.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with using `glob` for simplification, but instead of manually counting or whatnot, try:

```
$files = glob("dir/*.sql");
$files = array_combine($files, array_map("filemtime", $files));

arsort($files); // orders by mtime, newest files first
$files = array_keys($files);
$files = array_slice($files, 5);   // removes the first 5

array_map("unlink", $files);     // delete remaining list
```

But you could of course use a manual `foreach` in place of the `array_map`.

Comment: +1 - Indeed, but I'm deleting all but one, as I said in the post, the first method I found here on stack, and I tried to adapt it to delete all files but the last and most recent one when the `maxbackups` is exceeded ( that variable can be 3 or 30 or more ).

Comment: In this case the length parameter might do `array_slice(..., 5, -5)` or so.

Comment: OK, but why 5, -5 ? Wouldn't that be just `array_slice(..., 1)` ?